# Question mark (?) in XML attributes for Android

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

Can anyone explain the question mark means in Android XML attributes?

```
<TextView    
    style="?android:attr/windowTitleStyle"
    More attributes
/>
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The question mark means it's a reference to a resource value in the currently applied theme. See the [linuxtopia Android Dev Guide](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) or the [android.com Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes) for more about it.

`\?` escapes the question mark.

Comment: I think it would be better to point your second link to: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes

Comment: Dev Guide articles have been restructured, this is the new direct link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes

Comment: I think it's more appropriate to say ? is used to "Referencing style attributes" rather than "reference to a resource value in the currently applied theme". According to android.com dev guide link you provided.

Comment: I am still confused, even after reading the two links provided. What does  "reference to a resource value in the currently applied theme" mean exactly? Isn't a resource referenced with '@' taken from the current theme too? (for instance, @android:color/black)

Comment: @Tiago: The at sign (@) is required when you're referring to any resource object from XML.  It's not specific to themes.

Comment: I think it makes the most sense when considering multiple themes containing the same custom resource attribute. Say you have movie-related themes like MyThemeTransformers and MyThemeHobbit, and both have an attribute called movieIcon.  And movieIcon points to a @drawable resource, say a robot or a hobbit image, in each theme definition. You can refer to "?attr/movieIcon" anywhere the theme is in effect (like in a toolbar or dialog or whatever kind of View layout), and it will automatically point to the correct drawable when you switch between themes. I hope that helps.

Comment: @DevonBiere it helped! It'd be great if you submit your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 47):

The ? lets you refer to a style *attribute* instead of a specific *hard-coded resource*. See ["Referencing style attributes"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes) in the Android Dev Guide for details.

So, how is this actually useful?  It makes the most sense when considering **multiple themes** containing the **same custom resource attribute**.

Say you have movie-related themes like MyThemeTransformers and MyThemeHobbit, and both have an attribute called **movieIcon**. And that movieIcon attribute points to a different @drawable resource, say robot.png or hobbit.png, in each theme definition.

You can refer to "**?attr/movieIcon**" anywhere the theme is in effect (like in a toolbar or dialog or whatever kind of View layout), and it will automatically point to the correct drawable when you switch between themes.  You don't need any theme-dependent logic to use the different drawables. You just define the movieIcon attribute for each theme and the Android framework takes care of the rest.