# What's the difference between @android: and ?android:

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

What's the difference between

```
android:color="@android:color/black"
```

and

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

What's the difference between the `@` and `?` ?

This is one of those questions which is ungoogleable, or [ogooglebar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungoogleable).

Comment: From [Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html): To reference a style attribute, the name syntax is almost identical to the normal resource format, but instead of the at-symbol `(@)`, use a question-mark `(?)`, and the resource type portion is optional.

Comment: This is not an ungoogleable.... :)

Comment: The url slug for this question is funny.

Comment: @PankajKumar It was until I asked it and Google stuck it near the [top](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+%40android+%3Fandroid&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS526US526&aq=f&oq=android+%40&aqs=chrome.0.59j57j65l3j60.2289j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Notice the duplicate question is not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771871/237838) answer and its comments)

Prefixing the ID with a question mark indicates that you want to access a style attribute that's defined in a style theme, rather than hard-coding the attribute, as explained in  [Referencing Style Attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes).

More specifically, the `?` implies an extra level of indirection. Think of it as dereferencing a theme attribute to fetch the resource it points to rather than referring to the attribute itself. You see this with ?android:attr/foo

Answer (score 9):

**@android:color/black**

means you are referring to an color defined in the android namespace.
This namespace is the namespace of the framework.

search black in this file: [black color in framework](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml)

**style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"**

"?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" simply means "use the value defined by the attribute called borderlessButtonStyle in the namespace android." This attribute and its value are part of the Android framework, the "android" namespace.

[borderlessButtonStyle in framework](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml)

---

**Edited:** from this [Referencing Style Attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes)

this link tell us:

For example, here's how you can reference an attribute to set the text color to match the "primary" text color of **the system theme**:

```
<EditText id="text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Comment: Wow that is literally correct without actually answering the question.

Comment: check my edited ans and tell me what is the system theme?

Answer (score 1):

here Google has a document on it http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes