# what is the real difference between "android:" and "attr"?

Tags: android, xml, styles, themes

When I attemp to use some resource in activity_main.xml like that

```
    android:minHeight="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

I found some thing i can't understand.I know the "android:" means <s>system level attribute</s> when an XML parser reads the document, "attr" means the attribute in my theme(right?), but why some attribute should add the package name "android:",though there is a same attribute? such as i can define attribute in my styles.xml like this

```
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/purple</item>
```

but i also can define attribute like

```
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/purple</item>
```

My English is very bad,so mybe i haven't explain what i want to figure out.

Comment: `"android:" means system level attribute` no it does not - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684131/whats-the-difference-between-android-and-android) answer )

Prefixing the ID with a question mark indicates that you want to access a style attribute that's defined in a style theme, rather than hard-coding the attribute, as explained in Referencing Style Attributes.

More specifically, the ? implies an extra level of indirection. Think of it as dereferencing a theme attribute to fetch the resource it points to rather than referring to the attribute itself. You see this with `?android:attr/foo`