# What is difference between "?actionbarsize","?attr:actionbarsize" and "?android:actionBarSize"?

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-appcompat

I am confused about `"?actionbarsize"`,`"?attr:actionbarsize"`, `"?android:actionBarSize"?` and `?android:attr/actionBarSize`

I see there are actionbarSize in appcompat-v7 but **how this all diffrent value are works.**

Comment: When using AppCompat you usually have to declare twice your styles, one with the `android:` prefix and one without. This in order to be able to load the styles effectively across different devices and O.S.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between @android: and ?android:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684131/whats-the-difference-between-android-and-android)

Answer (score 2):

> ?attr

**The ?attr: syntax is used for accessing attributes of current
 theme.**

> @android

**you want to access a style attribute that's defined in a
style theme**

***EX :***

```
<Toolbar  
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" //?android
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar" /> //@android
```

check [accessing-resources guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes) from **developer.android.com**