# Android Style Syntax @android vs android

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

What is the difference between

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

And

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Notice the difference in the parent syntax of using `@android:style/` vs just using `android:`.

I have already seen [What's the difference between “?android:” and “@android:” in an android layout xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771844/whats-the-difference-between-android-and-android-in-an-android-layout-x) but note that my example doesn't include the question mark.

Answer (score 3):

They give the same results.

The `[package:]resource` syntax *(sugar?)* is probably easier and even gets autocomplete on Android Studio. The `parent` attribute is used for inheritance, thus the value must be a style resource when the attribute is coming from a `style` element. You can even use it with your own package, e.g. `com.example.mypsyapp:Oppagangnamstyle`.

The `@[package:]type/resource` syntax is valid for other non-style resources, e.g. `@android:drawable/bottom_bar` and `@string/my_string_id` in layout XML. In these cases, the `@` is needed to tell that whether the value is a literal string or a reference to a resource.

Potential useful links:

- [Android Style Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html)
- [Android Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance)
- [Android 5.1.0_r5 core source code values](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.0_r5/core/res/res/values/)

Answer (score 3):

I think that there is no particular difference when called in **style.xml**. , but :
Make a layout and place a **textview** there.
Set this code `android: textColor = "? Android: textColorSecondary"` inside the textview.
When using @android, you can only colorize the text that you created in src.
But when you use android, you'll see a lot of code opened from the **Android framework**.
To understand more, please check the **attrs.xml** file