# what does the question mark in layout item values mean?

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question mark (?) in XML attributes for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733907/question-mark-in-xml-attributes-for-android)

I've been browsing android source code and a few times i've come across '?' while specifying values for layout items. I know that '+' adds the value to R such as: `android:id="@+id/blah"`.

The specific example i'm looking at is `R.layout.simple_spinner_item`, particularly the line:

```
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
```

What does the '?' mean?

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733907/question-mark-in-xml-attributes-for-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733907/question-mark-in-xml-attributes-for-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733907/question-mark-in-xml-attributes-for-android

Comment: ah i see. sorry about the redundancy. probably need to close as duplicate.