# What does the ? in Android XML mean

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question mark (?) in XML attributes for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733907/question-mark-in-xml-attributes-for-android)

```
<TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />
```

what does "?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" do? Does it have a name? Why doesn't it use an "@" instead? Can I use this syntax in my own code? Where can I read more about this? Since I don't know what it is, it's kind of hard to find more information about it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

This question has already been asked on stackoverflow.
The answer given was:

> The question mark means it's a reference to a resource value in the
>   currently applied theme.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733907/question-mark-in-xml-attributes-for-android) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

It is a reference to style attribute. Check this reference:

[References To Theme Attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes)