# What does the "?" mean in android style declarations

Tags: android, android-styles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question mark (?) in XML attributes for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733907/question-mark-in-xml-attributes-for-android)

I have seen `?` in android style declarations. For example...

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/gems_button"
     style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:text="@string/gems_button" />
```

What does the `?` signify in the line `style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"`

Comment: I believe this means that the resource comes from a theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [reference to style attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes)

> A style attribute resource allows you to reference the value of an attribute in the currently-applied theme.

Comment: Thanks @AaronHe. I somehow missed that in the Android docs!