# what is the use of ? in android items when defining styles

Tags: android

I tried searching on Google but it removes **`?`** as one of the stopwords and I know it must be there but can't find it on developer's website. So just asking what does this symbol in the line below signify.

```
<style name  = ......
     <item name = "buttonBarStyle">?android:buttonBarStyle</item>....
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733907/question-mark-in-xml-attributes-for-android

Comment: Got it. Didn't know this was already asked. Thanks