# What is the difference between the two syntaxes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

```
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
```

Both are giving the same result. Is there any difference in there compilation efficiency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question mark (?) in XML attributes for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733907/question-mark-in-xml-attributes-for-android)

Comment: 1st is theme reference of inbuilt android lib and 2nd one is the attribute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
```

is text style setting directly.

```
android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
```

is the refrence text style that set value on this Activity or this TextView's Theme . Like this:

```
<style name="MyStyle">
<item name="textAppearanceSmall">@style/textStyle</item>
</style>
```