# Question Marks in each Preference Layout elements

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a custom preference layout called **preference_test.xml** using [com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages) in the build.gradle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_set_seralarm"
    android:key="key_seralarm"
    android:title="@string/ptit_seralarm" />

<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="1"
    android:entries="@array/service_time_entries"
    android:entryValues="@array/service_time_values"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_set_sertime"
    android:key="key_service_time"
    android:title="@string/ptit_sertime" />

<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_set_sermute"
    android:key="key_service_mute"
    android:title="@string/ptit_sermute" />
```

The application, settings and preference elements works perfect, but I notice weard “question marks” on the left panel of the palette in the

Design tab as show in the following image:

[image]

Using Android Studio 3.2.1
Any explanation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733907/question-mark-in-xml-attributes-for-android

Comment: ADM/AD10 Its not about question marks on the layout code, its about the question marks in Android Studio Layout DESIGN TAB (indicated in RED on the image)

Comment: @Adil did you find an answer?