# Xamarin Android Style Xml Attributes

Tags: android, xamarin

in the layout xml files that we create . we sometimes use '@' & '?' attribute what does it mean

For e.g i created toolbar.xml . i could see the **?android:attr/actionBarSize** what does this mean

& what does @android:style/**ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar" mean

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="**?android:attr/actionBarSize**"
    android:background="**?android:attr/colorPrimary**"
    android:theme="**@android:style/**ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

Comment: Do you understand the attributes right now?

Comment: Thanks i get it now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the document about `ResourcesFromCode`, you will find

if you use **@...**, that means [a syntax to reference a resource in an XML resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#fromXmlSyntax):

```
@[<package_name>:]<resource_type>/<resource_name>
```

And if you use **?...**, that means you are [referencing a style attribute and the resource type portion is optional](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ReferencesToThemeAttributes):

```
?[<package_name>:][<resource_type>/]<resource_name>
```

You can get more examples and detailed information in the [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ResourcesFromCode).

And here is a link that may help: [question-mark-in-xml-attributes-for-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733907/question-mark-in-xml-attributes-for-android)